# Opening R help function

Tags: r

I am running Windows 10 Pro on a 64-bit machine. I am using the latest version of R but have difficulty opening help documentation.

It works for a while, but then, completely out of nowhere, when running

```
?anyfunction
```

the browser (Firefox) will open a new tab with the message

```
Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection
```

I've seen that this error message pops up elsewhere in other situations, but they seem completely unrelated to this one.

What is going on here?

Comment: Try using `help(anyfunction)`, if the help command works that means  there is a possibility of conflict of "?", you may want to run conflicts() and see if there is "?" appears, In that case just remove rm("?") you may check for pryr::where("?"), What does it return?. Also try restarting the R session without saving anything at all in your .RData.

Comment: There seems to be no conflict: `help` and `?` produce the same error message. Restarting the console indeed solves the problem. This behavior is frequent however. I'll be working on something (usual calls: loading packages, running package or custom functions, plotting stuff, calling `help`) and at a certain point the latter function simply starts output this very strange error. Maybe somebody out there has experienced the same?